# Export opened Chrome tabs to a document, or bookmark them all

Tags: chrome-for-android

Using Android phone, how can I create a list of all my opened Chrome tabs to an Excel or Word file; or save them all in a new Bookmark Folder so I can close them all, but view them later?

Comment: Hi Heidi, sounds like you are might be looking for a session manager that allows you to save all the open tabs in a browser session and give the session a label. Then reopen it or another one at a later time by selecting it in the session manager.  Maybe use that to search for or a mobile browser that supports that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how from Android.

But from a PC it's easy, with adb (Install the [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) package if `adb` from your terminal doesn't work):

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
wget -O tabs.json http://localhost:9222/json/list
```

Look out for the popup on your phone when you run adb, and allow debugging. See the page at the platform tools above on how to do that, it's a menu setting on your phone.

Converting from it to Excel, you can do it online, or you can install Python and do it on your PC. Create a `convert.py` file with the following:

```
import pandas
pandas.read_json("tabs.json").to_excel("tabs.xlsx")
```

And run it:

```
python3 convert.py
```